# Vector Indexing, [,] vs [c(columns)] - what's the difference?

Tags: r

I'm having a data.frame which *does not currently have all same number of rows in it's column*. And I've noticed that using `dframe[c("column1", "column2")]` works fine, while `dframe[, c("column1", "column2")]` throws the error :

> Error in x.raw[, 1:3] : incorrect number of dimensions

Why does this occur? I've got the impression that both syntaxes are correct, and I usually use `[, ]` format for indexing, but here it does not work.

Comment: both syntaxes are correct. In your case you should check if it is a vector.

Comment: In what case would format dframe[c("column1", "column")] be the only choice?

Comment: As Mamoun said, you are probably seeing an error here because `x.raw` isn't actually a data.frame; try `dim(x.raw)` or `str(x.raw)` to investigate. A data.frame -- by definition -- has an equal number of rows in every column, by the way.

Comment: ahh yes. sorry about this. I returned it as a data.frame but I guess R forced it to be a list due to that the rows where not the same

Comment: The dimensions are being dropped in the second example. If you want to refer to it the same way use the `drop` argument like `dframe[, c("column1", "column2"), drop=FALSE]`